# How do I update my zsh prompt when an env variable changes?

Tags: environment-variables, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm using oh-my-zsh. My theme file looks like this:

```
PROMPT="${AWS_PROFILE}%(?:%{$fg_bold[green]%}➜ :%{$fg_bold[red]%}➜ )"
PROMPT+=' %{$fg[cyan]%}%c%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)'

ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX="%{$fg_bold[blue]%}git:(%{$fg[red]%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX="%{$reset_color%} "
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY="%{$fg[blue]%}) %{$fg[yellow]%}✗"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_CLEAN="%{$fg[blue]%})"
```

It's based on a popular theme. The only thing I have added is `${AWS_PROFILE}`.

The prompt does show my AWS profile as intended. But even if I the environment variable changes the prompt doesn't change. This is not as I had intended. It does change if I run `source ~/.zshrc`.

Can I make the prompt update when my env variable changes?

Comment: I took a look at how spaceship-prompt achieve this and it seems they use some zsh hooks to rerun things before every command. For example, here is how they set up the preexec and precmd hooks: https://github.com/spaceship-prompt/spaceship-prompt/blob/master/spaceship.zsh#L197

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about spaceship promt. I went ahaid and switched to that.

Comment: `AWS_PROFILE` is expanded immediately when you define `PROMPT`, since you used double quotes. Use single quotes, or consider using a precmd hook to set the value of `PROMPT`.

Comment: @user1283776 If you no longer need your question answered, then please close it, so it no longer appears in the list of unanswered questions. :)

Comment: Ok, I closed it. I needed to state a motivation and none of the options fit, so I chose one anyway.

Comment: It doesn't look like it's closed to me. I guess it's waiting for an admin to approve?

Answer (score 0):

Copying @chepner's comment into an answer:

AWS_PROFILE is expanded immediately when you define PROMPT, since you used double quotes. Use single quotes, or consider using a precmd hook to set the value of PROMPT.